# Move SQL Server database modification between development and live database without data

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I am working with SQL Server and I have two databases - one for development and another one for a live users.

I want a way to move the changes (create new tables, SP, functions, modifications, relations, indexes) from development database to a live database automatically

now I am copy the script for each element and execute it on the live database

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Most database changes can be scripted.

Comment: You should script your changes when you make them like any other code and put them in the appropraite place in your source control. Then you know exactly what scripts to run to put a particular change in place.

Comment: now I am copy the script for each element and execute it on the live database, but I think there is a better way. can you help?

Comment: @user1560793 Do you need to copy the data as well?

Comment: I found a solution and I write it below but I don't know how I can close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on Visual Studio 2010 in Scheme Compare under Data menue
I can choose the servers and databases I want to compare and then it will show the difference between it and the two databases and then we can automaticlly write these changes from source database to target database

Answer (score 0):

there are few ways how to achieve this. I don't want to make any advertisement here, but in my job I found [RedGate SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) most suitable to do this. Same can be achieved by using Visual Studio 2010 database project. Unfortunately I don't know any free tool actually.